# "Maximum Distance Exceeded" error when plotting course for passenger mission in Elite Dangerous

Tags: elite-dangerous

I got a passenger mission, where the destination is more than 5,000 light-years away. I'm trying to plot a course to the destination, in the Galaxy Map, but I'm getting an error saying "maximum distance exceeded." How do I get to my destination?

Comment: ...which a basic google search would have told you. A lot of your recent questions are showing a lack of any research effort whatsoever...

Comment: Another thing to mention is that we expect a certain level of effort here at Arqade.  While we allow self-answered questions, they're generally held up a higher level of scrutiny, as they may not actually be problems users will actually face.

Comment: It's also worth noting that retaliatory downvoting is frowned upon. You should be voting on things based on the content of the question or answer *not* who posted it. Note that the things I've downvoted of yours were *specifically because they lack research effort*, not because I have something against you personally.

Comment: I've actually found the answers to these questions, as I've learned how to play the game, so I'm documenting them for other people's benefit. I'm still learning new things on a regular basis, so I'll continue to document them to help other people learn from. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: We never said you couldn't answer your own questions.  We said they'd be subject to a bit more scrutiny.  Not everything you encounter is going to be worthy of a new question.

Comment: Feel free to scrutinize all you want, and use your votes as you see fit. That's how StackExchange works.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperspace jumps can only be plotted out to 1,000 light-years, so you'll need to find a star that's just under 1,000 light years away from your current location. Once you reach that destination, or a bit before then, plot your next 1,000 light-year segment, until you get there.

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/359320/discussions/0/483368526577781800/

Source 2: https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteDangerous/comments/4nvnj3/is_possible_to_increase_route_plotting_range/

Answer (score 0):

As of v2.4, Galaxy Map route plotting can now plot routes up to 20,000 lightyears.

v2.4 was released on September 26, 2017 for all platforms.

[Source](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Elite_Dangerous:_Horizons).